# Associate a label with apex:inputfield in a dynamically created form elements

Tags: visualforce

I am working on a VF page which we trying to get compliant to Section `508 1194.22 (o)` for people with disability issues. In the VF page we using fieldsets to dynamically create the form. All of these work fine.

But the issue is how do we associate a label to the apex:inputField?

The only way i think is to use `for` attribute on the label to the id of the `apex:inputfield`. Since we are dynamically creating the form fields within a `apex:repeat`, we would not be able to give an id to it. Is there any other way we can associate a label to inputfield?

```html
<apex:repeat value="{!AppFields}" var="f">  
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-xs-3">
            <apex:outputlabel styleclass="control-label " value="{!f.Label}" />
            <apex:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;font-weight:bold" 
                rendered="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}" />
        </div>
        <div class="control-label col-xs-9">
            <apex:inputField value="{!apps[f.fieldPath]}" 
                required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}" 
                styleClass="form-control source"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have a repeat statement and the form inputs is dynamic, if you include `for` to output label pointing to an `id` of input field, its sufficient to support the accessibility.

```html
<apex:repeat value="{!AppFields}" var="f">  
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-xs-3">
            <apex:outputlabel styleclass="control-label " value="{!f.Label}" 
                for="input-field"/>
            <apex:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;font-weight:bold" 
                rendered="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}" />
        </div>
        <div class="control-label col-xs-9">
            <apex:inputField value="{!apps[f.fieldPath]}" 
                required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}" 
                styleClass="form-control source"
                id="input-field"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

This works because the visualforce engine replaces the id's dynamically for all `apex` tags, making id unique for each element. Generated output based on a similar example:

[image]

Note: This will work as long as `apex:outputLabel` and `apex:inputField` are within the same parent apex tag.